# Coordinating CSS to HTML

Tags: html, css

I can't accurately target a section of CSS file to format a section of HTML file.

I'm trying to get the `tagline` section to render in green, but instead it renders in red.

This tells me that the styles are being applied to this section based on the body block of the CSS. How I get the CSS `tagline` block to apply to the `tagline` section of the HTML?

Here is the HTML narrowed down:

```
<body>
    <div id='container'>
        <main>
            <tagline>
                bunch of text
            </tagline>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is the relevant part of the CSS:
    @CHARSET "UTF-8";

```
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, dl, ol, form, fieldset, input, label, table, tbody, tfoot, th, tr, td, textarea, select 
{
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, Geneva, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#container {
    width:1280px;
}

// blue #5E91A8  <--these lines seem to be the problem!
// green #C1D82F

tagline {
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, Geneva, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:16px;
    color:green;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `font-color` doesn't exist, use `color`

Comment: Should be color, not font-color.

Comment: Thanks, but all of these miss the mark. It's not just the color (which I've changed in the post). It's the fact that my CSS isn't matching up with that section of the html file.

Comment: Can you please try to put your code in a Fiddle ? I've made a working example and don't understand why your (amended) code wouldn't work

Comment: Also, clean up your CSS by removing the `font-family` and `font-weight` from the `tagline`. It's already inheriting those from the `body` styles.

Comment: You'll need to show an example that demonstrates the problem. The most common problem is that there's a syntax error earlier in the CSS file and the browser stops parsing it.

Comment: Try to replace `tagline` with `span` for example, as suggested by @c-smile

Comment: @juhana - you got it. There was a comment line in the CSS that I didn't include here. Once i removed it, everything is fine. Please post an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `font-color` with `color` :

```css
tagline
{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id='container'>
        <main>
            <tagline>
                bunch of text
            </tagline>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your CSS.

To specify the font color it's simply `color: red;` and `color: green;`. Also, remove the # in #red. The # is only needed when specifying the color in numbers, ie `color: #ff0000;`.

```
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, dl, ol, form, fieldset, input, label, table, tbody, tfoot, th, tr, td, textarea, select {
        font-family:"Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, Geneva, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: red;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    #container {
        width:1280px;
    }
    tagline {
        font-family:"Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, Geneva, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size:16px;
        color:green;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/79mjyjoq/

Answer (score 0):

That is because the element inherits the properties from the higher level. You will have to override the property, like so:

```
tagline{ color:red;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not know about `tagline` elements.  But HTML5 do support custom elements.

By specification custom elements should have '-' inside their names. So this will work in all modern browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>

      tag-line {
        color:green;
      }    

    </style>
  </head>
<body>
    <div id='container'>
            <tag-line>
                bunch of text
            </tag-line>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does know `main` : http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element

Comment: Oddly some parsers will take it :) Stack Snippet applies the style to tagline :)